# jQuery DateTimePicker is subtracting one hour on input blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm having a strange annoying issue.

This [jQuery DateTimePicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) is subtracting 1 hour on input `blur`.

**Look closely...** Select a date and then a time. It will behave correctly until you focus out the input field.

I can't figure out...

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MrbQwb) for you to play with.
The CDNs used are from [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-datetimepicker).

```js
$('#start').datetimepicker({
  format:"Y-m-d h:i a",
  step:15
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.14/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.14/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="start">
```

Comment: It seems to only be an issue when you include the `a` flag for AM/PM, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why

Comment: right...removing format completely it doesn't do that. report  as a bug after you verify the format string is as documented

Comment: mmm... Right, I see it too. That's a bug I should report then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an open issue on project GitHub repository: Format "m/d/Y h:i a" changes hour onBlur #596
https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/596

btw, there is a workaround

```
$('#start').datetimepicker({
  format:"Y-m-d H:i A",
  validateOnBlur: false,
  step:15
});
```

Comment: Thanks al lot. Accepted solution because the fastest and having the existing issue link. ;)

Comment: Another (better) option is to update php-date-formatter at the to of the jquery.datetimepicker.full.js to the current version from https://github.com/kartik-v/php-date-formatter/blob/master/js/php-date-formatter.min.js.

Comment: still when I open the picker, it highlights time from 1 hour before.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behaviour was caused by `a` to show PM/AM in this format:

```
"Y-m-d h:i:m a"
```

When I set:

validateOnBlur:false

The time was not changed anymore. Or you can also remove `a` out of this format-definition.

```js
$('#start').datetimepicker({
  format:"Y-m-d h:i a",
  //format:"Y-m-d h:i", // or use it without a or A for PM/AM
  step:15,
  validateOnBlur:false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.14/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.14/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="start">
```

Answer (score 1):

So this worked for me:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  step: 15,
  format:"Y-m-d h:i a",
  validateOnBlur: false,
})
```

However, this still seems like a bug that needs to be addressed, but this may help you in the meantime.  This will allow for invalid times if a user changes the time in between when they use the date picker and when they focus off the input.

Working snippet here:

```js
$('#start').datetimepicker({
  format:"Y-m-d h:i a",
  step:15,
  validateOnBlur: false,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.14/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.14/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="start">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use MomentJS to fix this issue without altering the code as follows:

Put this somewhere on page load:

```
$.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter({
  parseDate: function (date, format) {
    var d = moment(date, format);
    return d.isValid() ? d.toDate() : false;
  },
  formatDate: function (date, format) {
    return moment(date).format(format);
  }
});
```

And pass these options when you init the DateTimePicker, explicitely passing the format options (as described on MomentJS docs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/):

```
$(selector).datetimepicker({
    lazyInit: true,
    format:'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
    formatDate:'DD/MM/YYYY',
    formatTime:'hh:mm A'
});
```

Comment: When using solution from @tetta, it solves problem in the text input but the picker still opens with one hour subtracted. This solution is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix.
The class which draws is `xdsoft_current`.

**Old Buggy Code - line 1891**:

```
if ((options.initTime || options.defaultSelect || datetimepicker.data('changed')) && current_time.getHours() === parseInt(h, 10) && ((!isALlowTimesInit && options.step > 59) || current_time.getMinutes() === parseInt(m, 10))) {
```

**Fixed by adding +1 after current_time.getHours()**:

```
if ((options.initTime || options.defaultSelect || datetimepicker.data('changed')) && current_time.getHours() +1 === parseInt(h, 10) && ((!isALlowTimesInit && options.step > 59) || current_time.getMinutes() === parseInt(m, 10))) {
```

Comment: Hi, where is above dode? i am not able to find line no 1891 in latest zip. could you please help?

Answer (score -2):

```js
$('#datepicker, #datepicker-2').datetimepicker({
   formatTime:'h:i A',
   format: 'M d, Y, h:i A', 
   validateOnBlur: false, /* use validateOnBlur as false */
   minDate: 0,
   step: 30,
  });
```

**Problem**: jQuery `DateTimePicker` is subtracting one hour on input blur.

**Analysis**: `validateOnBlur` this function is by default true. When we use format like `(format: 'M d, Y, h:i A')` it formats the space between h:i and A. On the result of this the format give us 1 hr less than the selected time.

**Solution**:

```
      $('#datepicker, #datepicker-2').datetimepicker({
             formatTime:'h:i A',
             format: 'M d, Y, h:i A',
             validateOnBlur: false, //use validateOnBlur as false
             minDate: 0,
             step: 30,
       });
```

Comment: mmm... I am not convinced your answer brings any light on that 2 years ago issue. What is new here? `validateOnBlur: false` was the answer.